# Ean-128 python barcode generator

Tags: python-3.x, django, gs1-128, gs1-ai-syntax

Is there any python library to generate ean128 barcode. I tried 'python-barcode' , but in that library there is no option for ean128.

Comment: why you are giving minus vote. i didnt find any package for that. i

Comment: I guess, because you didn't read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), especially #4. Your question is considered off topic.

Answer (score 6):

The person who originally asked this question may not benefit from this, but this is for those who are still looking for an answer.

Note: Code-128 is not same as GS1-128

I was also stuck with this issue a few days ago, and I finally managed to find a python library which supports the GS1-128(UCC/EAN-128) barcode.

The library I am referring to is called "treepoem". Strange name I agree that's what makes it so hard to find. It is a wrapper for BWIPP library. And it has a dependency on ghostscript as well. About the name; Barcode -> Bark ode -> Tree poem.

Important links:
1) Ghostscript; download and install it and also add its "bin" and "lib" folder to
   system's path variable. 
   https://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html
2)treepoem
    https://pypi.org/project/treepoem/
3) All-codes; here in the repository you will find all supported barcodes here.
   https://github.com/adamchainz/treepoem/blob/master/treepoem/data.py

```
import treepoem
image = treepoem.generate_barcode(
     barcode_type='gs1-128',  # One of the BWIPP supported codes.
     data='(01)14-digit-product-code')
image.convert('1').save('barcode.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that `EAN 128` is the same thing as `Code 128` (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_128). It seems to be supported by [python-barcode](https://bitbucket.org/whitie/python-barcode/overview)

There is an alternative lib with [code 128](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/code128/0.3)

Comment: thanks for your answer. i tried with python barcode code 128. but the barcode reader cannot read it.