# ean-128/gs1-128/sscc library support for generating barcodes in python

Tags: python, barcode, barcode-printing, gs1-128

https://github.com/WhyNotHugo/python-barcode/ provides code128 support and other EAN, but gs1-128/ean-128 barcodes are different from code128, and I'm not sure how could I change the code128 format into supporting this variant, or if somehing already exists to support it in python. the standard is documented here: https://www.gs1.org/sites/default/files/docs/barcodes/GS1_General_Specifications.pdf
, the SSCC  basically has an AI identifier on the beginning, an extension digit and a control digit; any clue on existing solutions for this particulally?

Comment: Hi Marie, welcome to stackoverflow. Your question appears to be a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48983538/ean-128-python-barcode-generator) which unfortunately does not have any satisfactory answers. Also I assume [you made this github issue](https://github.com/WhyNotHugo/python-barcode/issues/36) three hours ago, which is itself a duplicate [of this issue in the same github repo](https://github.com/WhyNotHugo/python-barcode/issues/3).

Comment: I recommend explaining your situation in more detail in [the original github issue](https://github.com/WhyNotHugo/python-barcode/issues/3) such as code using the library which generates a barcode that cannot be scanned by a specific kind of barcode scanner.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ean-128 python barcode generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48983538/ean-128-python-barcode-generator)